# How to print multiple objects in a single print statement in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, syntax, swift-playground

I'm building an app that fetches JSON-data from the OpenWeatherMap API.
In my app I have structs like these:

```
struct WeatherData: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let main: Main
    let coord: Coord
}

struct Main: Decodable {
    let temp: Double
}

struct Coord: Decodable {
    let lon: Double
    let lat: Double
}
```

In one of my print statements, I want to print out all the values from Coords in the one print statement, like this `print(decodedData.coord.lat)`

How should I format the print statement so it can print both the `lat` value and the `lon` value?

Comment: Do you mean `print(decodedData.coord.lat, decodedData.coord.lon)`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`print`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print) accepts a `Any...` as its first parameter. The first sentence in the documentation says:

> You can pass zero or more items to the `print(_:separator:terminator:)` function.

That means you can pass in any number of arguments in that position, and they will all get printed out:

```
print(decodedData.coord.lat, decodedData.coord.lon)
```

The two things will be separated by a space by default. You can pass in a `separator:` argument to specify what separator you want.